# send logs to syslog server using cpp

Tags: c++, logging, syslog

I need to send logs to `syslog server` using `cpp`. `Syslog server` maybe configured on `same machine` or `different machine` in the network. Syslog server maybe present on `windows or linux machine`. Is there any `third party` library which I can use to forward logs to the syslog server ? `Cpp` will be preferred option for me to code. If third party library is not present what will be better option ?

Comment: Why can't you just use the `syslog` function?   https://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog and then configure syslog on the machine you are running on to send the messages whereever you want them?

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes I saw `syslog` function. but I can use it for only linux, right? what should I use for windows systems where syslog server is configured ?

Comment: Technically it is just a logging format so it can be used anywhere. But I wouldn't use it even on linux.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the **syslog.conf** file, instead of the sy

Comment: If possible can you please help here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520886/why-syslog-sink-sends-same-records-on-all-the-sinks-when-a-sink-is-member-of-cla